# jasperreports html split text without whitespaces

Tags: jasper-reports

String example:

"fooTextExmaple" x 100

So, it looks like one large word **without whitespaces.**

I have no problems with same strings in pdf, however,
I have problems dealing with large text without whispaces while exporting to HTML.

It looks like long row which does not fit any fixed width. The row's width would change dynamically by adding new chars without whitespaces to this string:

[image]

Is there any way to deal with this problem?

EDIT:

The way like it does not work:

```
 PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                resp.setContentType("text/html");
                req.getSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, print);
                exporter = new HtmlExporter();

                SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();
                configuration.setWrapBreakWord(true);
                exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

                exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
                SimpleHtmlExporterOutput output = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out);
                String[] uriParts = req.getRequestURI().split("/");
                output.setImageHandler(new WebHtmlResourceHandler("/" + uriParts[1] + "/image?image={0}"));
                exporter.setExporterOutput(output);
                exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks` property to `true`.

Read more about it at http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html

The `net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.wrap.break.word` property is supposed to help as well, but it only works in some browsers.

Comment: Should i use it for exporter?
I've tried line.breaks - does not work, like configuration.setWrapBreakWord(true);

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to work.  The only solution might be to set net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks (in the report or in jasperreports.properties).

Comment: found it. thanks, post your last comment as an answer please.